# How do you setup StandardML on MacOS Catalina

Tags: zsh, sml, smlnj, macos-catalina

I have installed by following the instruction here http://smlnj.org/dist/working/110.96/index.html. On that page you have to choose [smlnj-amd64-110.96](http://smlnj.cs.uchicago.edu/dist/working/110.96/smlnj-amd64-110.96.pkg).

I clicked on the downloaded package and clicked open which opens the an installer.

[image: mac installer]

Once this is done. I open a terminal and type `sml` I get `zsh: command not found: sml`.

If I change directory to `/usr/local/smlnj/bin` and run `./sml` I get the `sml` prompt.

```sh
➜  bin ./sml               
Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.96 [built: Fri Dec 13 14:59:34 2019]
```

My understanding is that adding `smlnj` to my path like:

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/smlnj/bin:$PATH
// or
export PATH=${HOME}/smlnj/bin:$PATH
```

I should get the prompt by typing `sml` but instead I get: `zsh: command not found: sml`.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I had added the `path` to my `./bash_profile` file. By adding it to `.zshrc` instead and restarting the terminal, it worked.

```sh
# SMLNJ
export PATH=/usr/local/smlnj/bin:$PATH
```

Then restart terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: Add it to `.zprofile`, not `.zshrc`, unless you have explicitly configured  your terminal emulator to start a non-login shell instead of a login shell.

Comment: A side note since this was hectic for me. If you are using vscode as your editor you can get sml formatting with https://github.com/stonebuddha/vscode-better-sml. Be sure to add `  "[sml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "stonebuddha.vscode-better-sml"
  },` to your `settings.json`